# Добавление изображений в Блок HTML в конструкторе Tilda

Tags: html

Только начала разбираться с конструктором Tilda и у меня возник вопрос.

Как добавить изображения в блоке T123?

Я хочу сделать полностью кастомный блок, сверстала его и тут встал вопрос изображений. Как их добавить, не используя другие блоки?

Comment: каким боком конструктор Tilda имеет отношение к html ?

Comment: не совсем по теме, но мне помогло) спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в блок 123 вы загрузить изображение не сможете, однако вы можете загрузить его в какой-нибудь другой блок (например галерею), сохранить и скопировать оттуда URL на изображение.

Ещё как вариант - загрузить изображение на сторонний сервер (например Vkontakte) и взять ссылку оттуда.

Дальше вы можете просто вставить в HTML блок код изображения.

Например:

```
<img src="https://sun9-55.userapi.com/c844520/v844520402/1cd36/tJbzcDFrOAU.jpg" alt="Описание изображения"/>
```

Даст вам результат:

[image: Описание изображения]

В том же ВК сохраняется не только обработанная и сжатая версия файла, но и оригинал (если требуется прикрепить его).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, решила этот вопрос с помощью использования сторонних ресурсов.

Comment: @Вита Рад помочь. Буду благодарен за принятие ответа и "стрелку вверх". (Я тут ради репутации профиля).